# "Android target: avdmanager: Command failed with exit code 1" when running Meteor Android

Tags: android, meteor

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.
I installed java 8, android studio and all dependencies listed [here](https://guide.meteor.com/mobile.html#installing-prerequisites). When I run

`meteor run android-device`
I get the following error:

```
Your system does not yet seem to fulfill all requirements to build apps for Android.

Please follow the installation instructions in the mobile guide:
http://guide.meteor.com/mobile.html#installing-prerequisites

Status of the individual requirements:        
✓ Java JDK                                    
✓ Android SDK                                 
✗ Android target: avdmanager: Command failed with exit code 1
✓ Gradle
```

`java -version` output:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_212"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-8u212-b03-0ubuntu1.18.04.1-b03)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.212-b03, mixed mode)
```

`javac -version` output:

```
javac 1.8.0_212
```

I have tried both using AVD or a physical android phone but I get same error.

Another error I get by running AVD standalone is that AVD starts but the virtual phone screen remains black, never starts.

Answer (score 1):

Provide a way to set $JAVA_HOME path.

On macOS 10.5

paste below code in your bash_profile (if you use bash)

```sh
#JAVA
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export CLASS_PATH=$JAVA_HOME/lib
```

Make config work
`source ~/.bash_profile`

Check variable
`echo $JAVA_HOME`

If you find there has some out message, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set sdk path. Run below commands in your project console. Change ANDROID_HOME to your sdk path

```
export ANDROID_HOME="/home/Android/Sdk"

export PATH="${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}tools/:${ANDROID_HOME}platform-tools/"
```

After setting up the sdk path run below command to start your application in android emulator

meteor run android

Answer (score 0):

JAVA_HOME path was wrongly set. I found this out by executing avdmanager from terminal (Android/SDK/tools/bin/avdmanager) and the error was more explicit there.